# How to transform these output into a matrix format

Tags: python

[image]

I wrote a code that displays a 4x4 tkinter entry widget. So when I input the values in each entry boxes and after pressing the "Matrix Form" button to print the output, it prints like this in the shell:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

What I would like to achieve is to print like this format:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,10,11,12],
 [13,14,15,16]]
```

Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import tkinter.font
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

fourbyfour = Tk()
fourbyfour.wm_geometry("420x400+0+0")
fourbyfour.wm_title("4X4 Matrix Calc")
fourbyfour.focus_set()
fourbyfour.grab_set()

myFont = tkinter.font.Font(family = 'Helvetica' , size = 12, weight = 'bold')

def getmatrix():
    for row in rows:
        for col in row:
            m = col.get()
            print(m)

rows = []
for i in range(4):
    cols = []
    for j in range(4):
        e = Entry(fourbyfour,width=10,font=myFont,bd=5)
        e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
        cols.append(e)
    rows.append(cols)

Calculate_2 = Button(fourbyfour, text = "Matrix Form",
                 font = myFont, bd=4, command = getmatrix,
                 bg = 'light blue', height = 2 ,width = 8)
Calculate_2.grid(row=5, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `np.reshape`, for example, for your case

`np.reshape(YOUR_ARRAY, (4, 4))`

would get you the desired output